# Raspberry Pi "ImportError: libavg/avg.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory"

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, importerror

I've looked all over for this. I've found similar problems but the fixes for them don't seem to work for me.

In a script when I run the line (or rather when it hits the line)

```
from avg import *
```

it throws an error

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libavg/avg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I've tried adding it to the path (both the *folder* `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libavg/` and the *file* `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libavg/avg.so`) and to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it doesn't make a difference. I've tried updating, upgrading, and even did an `apt-get` on it again just in case.

I'm not a longtime veteran Linux user, but I'm not too much of a noob, but this sure is making me feel like one.

As far as hardware goes, this is taking place on a Raspberry Pi. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Edit: The avg.so file exists in the spot that it says (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libavg) and I'm running it as the only user my Raspberry pi has, that being the administrator "Pi." I don't know if its simlinked nor how to tell if it is. I can CAT the file and it gives me a billion odd characters, however since it's an .so and not a .py or anything like it, opening it only shows characters from being compiled.

Edit 2: So after looking for a while I've found that avg.so is a linked file. Would that make a difference and, if so, how would I fix something like that, since from avg import * is a bit important for what I'm doing?

Comment: Where did you get this copy of libavg from?

Comment: I understand it was installed using atp-get, am I correct? Does the file in question exist? Is it a symlink? Does your user has permissions to read it? If all of the above is kosher, can you open the file and check if it has Python stuff?

Comment: You can use the command `nm` to inspect a shared library. A python library should have things like `PyArg_ParseTuple`, `PyDict_DelItem`

Answer (score 2):

Few check to do:

## What does the message tell?

```
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libavg/avg.so:`
 `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

So you shall check:

- does the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libavg/avg.so` really exists?
- if so, does the user running the code enough privileges to open it or even see it?

## The `avg.so` file is probably missing

Assuming, the `avg.so` shall be part of `libavg`, then there is an issue  [# 495: LibAVG master won't compile on RPi](https://github.com/libavg/libavg/issues/495)

This is the root of your problem to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem is actually in the new libavg structure. For some reason their file structure (according to their website) of their new build doesn't like Raspberry Pi.
As such, although the file is right where it says it is, the RPi has a hard time finding it via the libavg libraries.
Just have to wait for libavg to fix this.